# Why am I getting this error? AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a registration page with email verification. I am new in Python Dajngo webdevelopment. Currently I using Python 3.6, Django 2.2.4, Postgresql 11 and Ubuntu OS. But I am having a problem and can't figure it out. Guys could you please help me to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

I have provided all the code bellow:

**Here is the Error I am getting:**

```
AttributeError at /register/
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Exception Location: /media/coduser/KAPTRANS/ProgrammingProj-2/test/ChhichhiProject_comment_done/ChhichhiProject/chhichhi_project/users/views.py in register, line 36
Python Executable:  /media/coduser/KAPTRANS/ProgrammingProj-2/test/ChhichhiProject_comment_done/ChhichhiProject/env/chhichhi/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/media/coduser/KAPTRANS/ProgrammingProj-2/test/ChhichhiProject_comment_done/ChhichhiProject/chhichhi_project',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/media/coduser/KAPTRANS/ProgrammingProj-2/test/ChhichhiProject_comment_done/ChhichhiProject/env/chhichhi/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Aug 2019 09:37:05 +0000
```

**This is settings.py file**

```
"""
Django settings for chhichhi_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "2ba!+2akp+w%d_dfhj)u_@+rg&t8)r$&uyfwza+cza4jv55cyr"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig', # new
    'comments.apps.CommentsConfig', # new
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig', # new    
    'crispy_forms', # 3rd party form styler
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chhichhi_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chhichhi_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'cicidb1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1324pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog_home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# my custom local host mail server
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
# my custom local host mail server
# EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
# EMAIL_PORT =  465
# EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = True


# END custom mail server
```

**This is views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Email verification
from django.http import HttpResponse
# from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
# from .forms import UserSignUpForm
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, 
urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .token_generator import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
# Email verificatin end


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('activate_account.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('We have sent you an email, please confirm your email address to complete registration')
            # username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            # messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in.')
            # return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form': form})


def activate_account(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_bytes(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Your account has been activate successfully')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

**This is urls.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.register, name='register_user'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate_account, name='activate'),
]
```

**This is token_generator.py file**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )


account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

**This is main urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('register/', include('users.urls')), # new url
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name = 'users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', 
            auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name = 'users/password_reset.html'), 
            name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', 
            auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name = 'users/password_reset_done.html'), 
            name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
            auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name = 'users/password_reset_confirm.html'), 
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', 
                auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name = 'users/password_reset_complete.html'), 
                name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**This is the register.html file**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Registration{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                 <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                 {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You need to show the full error trace, otherwise we have to do a lot of work to try and figure out which line of code is producing your error. Or just tell us which line of your code is producing the error, if you can read your error trace.

Comment: the error is in your views.py, `register()` method, line 36. Can you tell us which is line 36 (and you can probably remove all the other code from your question).

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for coming to help me. Thanks for your suggestion. Now I have added the full error trace at the beginning. Could you please check it out now?

Comment: `Exception Location: /media/coduser/KAPTRANS/ProgrammingProj-2/test/ChhichhiProject_comment_done/ChhichhiProject/chhichhi_project/users/views.py in register, line 36
`

Comment: @dirkgroten this is line 36: 

**'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),**

Comment: why do you have `.decode()`? as the error tells you, a `str` object does not have a method `decode()`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I was following a tutorial where it has also used .decode(). Besides I have read another post where that post said to use .decode() with django newer version

Comment: See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlsafe_base64_encode), your tutorial is probably for an older version of Django, since 2.2, `urlsafe_base64_encode()` returns a `str` so you don't have to decode it.

Comment: @dirkgroten Okay I am going to that post and let you know what happened. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @dirkgroten Have you got any solution? I'm still struggling...

Comment: @dirkgroten 
Dude, you have solved my problem. I have removed .decode() from 'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode() now it looks like 'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)), and also has routed the proper template path just locating the users app template directory message = render_to_string('users/activate_account.html', I am very thankful to you my dear. Have a great day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should learn to read your error traces, usually they tell you exactly what's going on.

In this case the error location (`Exception Location`) was the line

```
'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()
```

and the error was `str` type does not have attribute `decode`, meaning that

```
urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
```

is apparently `str`, not a byte-string and therefore you cannot apply the method `decode` to it. The next step is to check the [documentation for urlsafe_base64_encode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlsafe_base64_encode) where you'll read that in Django 2.2, this returns a `str`.

Great! So with Django 2.2, no need to decode what used to be `bytestring`, just pass the string that you got from `urlsafe_base64_encode` directly to your mail template.

Comment: Thanks DIRKGROTEN for your valuable advice. I have read that article you recommended now, but can't figure it out how to implement the right usage of .decode(). Can you please tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't decode. That's all. There's no need anymore since it's already a string.

Comment: Dude DIRKGROTEN you have solved my problem. I have removed .decode() from 
**'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()** 
now it looks like **'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),**
and also has routed the proper template path just locating the users app template directory **message = render_to_string('users/activate_account.html',**
I am very thankful to you my dear. Have a great day!