# Django - 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run my Django project, but whenever i register a new account, i'm getting the following error: `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I don't understand where is this coming from; for authentication and registration i'm using `django-allauth`, and until now i've never had this issue. What could be the problem here? Here is the full traceback (i'm using Django 3):

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/?next=/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['channels',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'faqs.apps.FaqsConfig',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_otp',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
 'two_factor',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'rest_framework_mongoengine',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 46, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

During handling of the above exception (User matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py", line 244, in dispatch
    response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\two_factor\views\core.py", line 99, in post
    return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\two_factor\views\utils.py", line 128, in post
    return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py", line 294, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 214, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 72, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 50, in authenticate
    UserModel().set_password(password)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 98, in set_password
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 77, in make_password
    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 416, in encode
    return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, data.decode('ascii'))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/login/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: @ggorlen i'm not calling that, i'm using a library which handles authentication on Django; this error happens whenever i try to register a new account

Comment: try this `your_str_value.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @ggorlen The only thing i'm doing is typing password and email into the field from my browser, there is no code from me here, it's all into the library

Comment: Potential helpful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689928/why-am-i-getting-this-error-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-deco

Comment: You've most likely plumbed things together incorrectly. Check your Django settings files for incorrect allauth options and check your auth form templates for errors

Comment: @ggorlen This is django, this is why i'm executing it from the browser; the reason i didn't post code it's because the code is entirely Django-allauth. I did not write my own code to handle authentication, i decided to handle it entirely from Allauth for security reasons

Comment: It could be a settings/migrations error, i'm looking for this right now

Comment: do not fear to look into source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py from the error output. it complains about the data returned by the password hasher. so you may want to look at the password hashers in your settings, and see if any dependent library are installed on your system (bcript for example)